# Doctrine ODM/SF4. 1: Must return results instead of cursor

Tags: symfony4, doctrine-odm

I am trying to use query builder of doctrine odm with Symfony 4.1.
I have created a repository :

```
public function myFunction(Foo $foo)
{
    $query Builder = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
      ->eagerCursor(true) 
       ->field('foo')->references($foo)
       ->field('date')
       ->lte('2018-10-19 23:59:59')
       ->gte('2018-10-19 00:00:00');

    return $queryBuilder;
```

}

In my Controller :

```
$bars = $this->dm->getRepository(Bar::class)->myFunction($foo)->getQuery()->execute();

return new JsonResponse($bars);
```

Unfortunately, this returns me a EagerCursor class instead of my Array Collection. 
I also tried toArray with no result..

I have made some searches here, on Google and on doctrine Doc, in vain.

Do you have any tip for getting my ArrayCollection returned like doctrine or please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need an `ArrayCollection` just to stuff it into `JSONResponse` but you need to create it manually:

```
$bars = new ArrayCollection($this->dm->getRepository(Bar::class)->myFunction($foo)->getQuery()->execute()->toArray());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
It was simple actually, I've forgot to add ->find() to my query..

Nice day :)